# Why use the ternary operator to set a boolean variable?

Tags: php, casting, boolean, facebook-php-sdk

I am delving into the facebook php api and I saw the following function.

```
public static function enableAppSecretProof($on = true)
{
  static::$useAppSecretProof = ($on ? true : false);
}
```

So in my understanding this will set the variable $useAppSecretProof to true if $on evaluate to true and false if it evaluates to false.

Why would you set a boolean variable like this and not directly? Is this being used for casting? In other words, whatever value is passed as a parameter to the function will be cast as a boolean and that will be the value of the variable?

Comment: It should be `static::$useAppSecretProof = (bool)$on;`

Comment: Ah, so a cast is required.

Comment: While a cast could (and arguably should) be used for such conversion, consider that PHP is note statically typed and would allow `enableAppSecretProof(0)`. The use of `$on ? true : false` (an implicit conversion) or `(bool)$on` (an explicit cast/conversion) ensure that the value assigned is always true *or* false; nothing else. Ref [PHP Boolean](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php).

Comment: So the casting is necessary to ensure the type of the value stored in the variable. If the function is called incorrectly (for example if passed the string "false"), it will set the variable to true. But the use of the ternary operator in place of the casting operator gives no additional features, it is simple a matter of style?

Comment: They both have the same result: `$on ? true : false` is semantically equivalent to `(bool)$on ? true : false` (the conversion happens implicitly). Since `(bool)` is guaranteed to return a boolean the `x?true:false`, where x in {true,false}, can be trivial rewritten as the identity `x` (e.g. `(bool)$on`) .. Although I don't want to say it's "just style" either.

Comment: I guess this strategy to cast whatever value you receive to ensure you have a boolean is okay if it is not imperative to set the value as the user intended. It seems open to unexpected behaviour, shouldn't it complain about being given a non-boolean argument?

Answer (score 2):

Using the ternary achieves the effect of implicitly casting the parameter to the correct (bool) type.

The better way is:

```
static::$useAppSecretProof = (bool)$on;
```